# ansible template - making it dry if possible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is there any way to dry correctly this block, using a `default()` filter?

```
{% if item.aliases is defined %}
   server_name {{ item.target }} {{ item.aliases|join(" ") }}
{% else %}
  server_name {{ item.target }};
{% endif %}
```

I tried without any success =>  `error: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'item'`

```
  {{item.target item.aliases|join(" “)|default( item.target ) }}
```

I also tried this, but not giving the expected result.

```
    server_name {{[item.target ,item.aliases|default('')]|join(' ')}};

    # this print :  
    #    server_name actual.domain.com ['alias1.domain.com', 'alias2.domain.com'];
    # and my expected result is
    #    server_name actual.domain.com alias1.domain.com alias2.domain.com ;
    #  or ( when item.aliases is not defined 
    #    server_name actual.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

got it ... my print statement was wrong :

```
  server_name {{item.target}} {{item.aliases|default('')|join(' ')}};
```

output

```
  server_name actual.domain.com alias1.domain.com alias2.domain.com ;
  # or
  server_name actual.domain.com;
```